# Is it possible to call the function in controller based on certain page without frontend plugin?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

When i open a site in Typo3, i want the site to call a certain controller for that site and then output the layout. Preferably with the same name like "TestController.php" for the controller and "Test.html" for the layout.

I know that it's possible with FrontEnd plugin. The problem with FrontEnd plugin is that i need to add the plugin to the site that i want. What i really want is to write an extension, that once installed will work on all sites.

Is it actually possible to do this in typo3? Maybe with some configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

You can add TYPO3 plugins also via TypoScript and `USER` or `USER_INT` content object. With that it's easy to have a plugin on any page.

The famous [news extension](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/IntegrationWithTypoScript/Index.html#add-news-by-typoscript) gives a good example:

```
lib.news = USER
lib.news {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = News
  pluginName = Pi1
  vendorName = GeorgRinger

  switchableControllerActions {
        News {
          1 = list
        }
  }

  settings < plugin.tx_news.settings
  settings {
        //categories = 49
        limit = 30
        detailPid = 31
        overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty := addToList(detailPid)
        startingpoint = 13
  }
}
```

For more info about `USER` or `USER_INT` please have a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html).

Comment: if i don't get it wrong, the news extension is used to output the same data for all pages? What i mean is that on big project, for example if page = 1, then the controller for page 1 and also the view would be called. When i open page=2, controller and view for that page would be called. For every pages there's a different controller and view. Is it possible actually?

Comment: I don't exactly get why you would want to do it like that but it's possible to pass e.g. the current page id to the controller and then let the controller decide what to display.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

With TYPO3 v9 the Middlewares came to the Core, so you now have the possibility to run code at every position of page rendering you want.
A good documentation and example you can find here: https://usetypo3.com/psr15-middleware-in-typo3.html

Just add your own middleware, call your code every time or when some condition is met. Without plugin and on every page.

Beware, it's fancy! :-)

Answer (score -1):

For the time being I can also reccomend a middleware like Thomas Löffler adviced. But in my knowledge you have to identify all pages where you want to do something by the page id (which does not really seem elegant). 
And with many pages the "main-function" of the middleware, which is "process()" If I remember correctly, becomes really long.
So Iam also looking for an automatic name-based Layout<->Controller-Configuration of some kind.

I once found an interesting piece of information on [following site](https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/advanced-provider-extensions/custom-flux-controllers/controller-actions.html)

```
our template files inside for example the Content subfolder are - according to Extbase conventions - 
connected directly to a Controller's action. In standard Extbase, the Controller action must exist 
first and will then cause the template file to be rendered - in Fluid Powered TYPO3 this is reversed 
(since your Controller is optional)
```

This site concentrates on the Flux-extension but I hoped that there could be a global convention of some kind.

So any new idea or piece of information in connection with a global view-controller configuration without having to use the TYPO3-backend to connect both would really be useful! (using TYPO3 9 and a fluid-based view-layer)